# Do I need to define a constructor when using @Autowired?

Tags: spring

Since @AutoWired tells the application context to inject an instance of UserService here 
is there a need for the UserController constructor ?

```
@Autowired
private UserService service;

public UserController(UserService service) {
    this.service = service;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The dependency will be injected automatically by Spring Framework, provided that you enabled annotation scan for the package the class is in.